# How to compare class to any type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How to compare class (schema) to data of any type

for example:

`schema class`

```
class Element {
    name!: string
    age?: number
}
type DataType = Element[]
```

`some variable`

```json
[
    {
        "name": "mike"
    },
    {
        "name": "john",
        "age": 14
    }
]
```

I want to know if the data matches the circuit description

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compare"?

Comment: @Alexander , I want to know if the data matches the circuit description

Comment: ThereIt's... not a circuit? But anyways, I think the word you're looking for is "validate". Googling "json schema validation" should point you in the right direction

Comment: @Alexander, yes, I want to write own validation package. But I don't have much experience with ts. It somethig like `nest` dto's

Comment: "yes, I want to write own validation package." that's something you should mention in the question. You also need to show your attempt. Open ended "write my code for me" questions aren't welcome here, because this isn't a free code-writing service